# MFC C++ Language Resource DLL - only override some dialogs

Tags: c++, mfc, localization

I have successfully made a resource only DLL, and placed some dialogs, that were in the main exe.  So I have Test.exe, and TestENU.dll.   It works fine, but I am trying to find a way to only override some dialogs, instead of being required to have all exactly the same dialogs, and instead pull some from the base exe, as my real project has around 40 dialogs, and I only want to have to translate some, slowly over time.

(I used this link to do satellite/resource dll)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default resources (including dialogs) are governed by the current setting of the resource handle.  You can set the resource handle at any time using [AfxSetResourceHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ws31ff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to point to a resource only dll, or, your executable.  You'll need to be prudent in making sure that the handle is pointing to the correct resource location **before** instantiating a dialog, so, you'll need to save the current handle before changing it to a new resource handle, and, changing it back when you are done.

Comment: Is there a way to see if a dialog or resource exists, in the resource dll?  Or is there a way to scan between the main exe, and the resource DLL of language, identify which are which, so I can make a table for loading purposes?

Comment: [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx) should do it.

Comment: The final piece seems to be, how do you know which language pack resource DLL was automatically loaded?  The page seemed to have a 5 step process, but it wasn't clear to me how to know which DLL it ended up with.  Or perhaps can use AfxGetResourceHandle(), then see if any dialogs are missing, and if so load the main exe for those?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but, you can use [EnumResourceTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648039(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine what resources exist in the executable or the resource dll.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a template ID to the constructor of your dialogs.

Constructor:

```
CTestDlg::CTestDlg(int Template, CWnd* pParent = NULL) : CDialog(Template)
{   
    ...
```

Call:

```
int idd;
if (bTestDialogTranslationExists)
    idd = IDD_TESTDIALOG_FROM_DLL;
else
    idd = IDD_TESTDIALOG;
CTestDialog dlg(idd);
dlg.DoModal();
```

This code is for demonstration only. You might want to derive a new class from CDialog that handles localized dialog templates automatically, depending on, for example, if the Template exists in a replacement map.

```
// have this as a global variable or in your CWinApp class
CMap <int, int, int, int> translatedDialogsMap;

// put this maybe in you CWinApp::InitInstance before any dialog could possibly be displayed
translatedDialogsMap[IDD_TESTDIALOG]  = IDD_TESTDIALOG_FROM_DLL;
translatedDialogsMap[IDD_TESTDIALOG2] = IDD_TESTDIALOG2_FROM_DLL;
translatedDialogsMap[IDD_TESTDIALOG3] = IDD_TESTDIALOG3_FROM_DLL;

...

// check in your dialog subclass constructor code, if a mapped dll dialog exists
int idd_replaced;
if (translatedDialogsMap.Lookup(Template, &idd_replaced))
    Template = idd_replaced;
```

Comment: It is an interesting solution and I appreciate, but one problem I see is you would need to give a new IDD to every dialog, in every language.

Comment: I thought you wanted formal identical dlls from which only the one with the desired language is being installed. Doesn't really make sense to load all language dlls at runtime -- unless you want to change the language while the application is running. But why would you then want distinct dlls? Or why do you think it's a problem to have the same IDDs in different dlls?

Comment: Maybe got lines crossed, I have around 40 dialogs, and I want to slowly start porting them to other languages, one by one, using same dialog IDDs, but different values for strings.  But I'd like to not have to tackle all 40 at once, port a couple key ones and release, and it seems like MFC's resource dlls required full identical dialogs in both.

Comment: If you really need the same IDDs in your extension dll and in the main application, rrirower's approach might be the right one. I personally won't prefer it because you constantly would have to patch your dlls resource.h file to make sure the IDDs are the same in the application and in the dlls, which can be more cumbersome than just adding a new IDD synchronously in all your language dlls every now and then plus adding a map entry. ...

Comment: ... The map solution would give you a sense of control over what dialog has actually been translated and, for example, may need to be revised in the language dlls, if a change in the default dialog was made. But this may be subject to personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 I am in the process of doing the same thing - trying to localize only some resources. Like the author, I am having a very hard time, and the solution has not been found yet. Here's what I can say after reading countless articles on the subject, some making careless statements that cost hours of work just to see that they don't work.

**Given** : you have an EXE with "default" resources and an extension DLL that replaces only some of then (I specifically tested it on strings so far).

1. The resource handle (`AfxGetResourceHandle()`) points to the EXE
2. If the DLL is properly loaded, it's placed in the search list for resources
3. The search process is as follows:
   a. The resource handle module (EXE) is searched
   b. If not found, the extension DLL resources are searched

Given this order, if the EXE has the needed resource, it wins. In our task it always does, so the DLL is as good as not loaded - useless.
Some people suggest setting the DLL module as the resource handle (`AfxSetResourceHandle`), claming it will reverse the order. DO NOT do it. It will not reverse the order, and here's why.
Doing so will replace the EXE's handle by the DLLs, that's all. It's a one liner in the MFC source. Now the search process will go as follows:

1. The resource handle (`AfxGetResourceHandle()`) now points to the DLL
2. The DLL is searched
3. If not found, the extention DLL resources are searched again!

This is because extension DLLs are added to a search linked list when loaded, but the EXE (I should say the resource handle that defaults to the EXE) is not! It is handled separately upfront. Replacing the resource handle does nothing to the linked list.

Setting the resource handle to the DLL makes EXE-based resources unavailable, so you end up with only localized resources, and now your program will most likely not start up.

I don't see a way (yet) to add the EXE to this list. The type required is (roughly) "extension DLL", you can't just do a `new CDynLinkLibrary` call.

What I am thinking is separating out even the default resources into a DLL. That way both DLLs become equal and get added to the search list. The precedence will, I suppose, be governed by the `LoadLirary` call order, so if you first load the localized DLL and then the "main", you should be OK.

P.S. Creating resources in two languages inside the EXE, while doable, has  proven to be a nightmare - it has never worked the way you'd want: first the selected UI language (see `SetThreadUILanguage`) then, if not found, the main in any language available. Comments on StackOverflow say "make DLLs, it's the only way" without going into details why.